# Css button width as percentage? Responsive button issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My problem here is that whenever I make my register and login forms the button elements won't stay to the width I set (75%). It's either too large or too small dependent on how I resize. You can see if you run the code that it's uneven compared to the form-container or text inputs.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Notes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/animation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/verification.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header-wrapper">
        <h1 id="banner">Notes</h1>
        <button id="register-btn">Register</button>
        <button id="login-btn">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="register-form-container">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="username" class="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Sign Up">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="login-form-container">
      <form action="php/login.php" method="post">
        <input type="username" class="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);

* {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}

#header-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#banner {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

#register-btn {
  float: left;
}

#login-btn {
  float: right;
}

#register-btn, #login-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

#register-btn:hover, #login-btn:hover {
  color: #004C3D;
}

#register-form-container, #login-form-container {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.username {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.username, .password {
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}

.submit-btn {
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 12.5%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  border: none;
}

.username:focus, .password:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ECAED;
}
```

Jquery (pretty sure this is obsolete to the question)

```
var isOpen = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#register-btn").click(function() {
    if(isOpen) {
      isOpen = false;
      $("#register-form-container").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      isOpen = true;
      $("#register-form-container").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

  $("#login-btn").click(function() {
    if(isOpen) {
      isOpen = false;
      $("#login-form-container").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      isOpen = true;
      $("#login-form-container").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0t1m4ae/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply this:

```
.username, .password, .submit-btn {
  padding: 0px 0px; /* You could put here something custom, like 0px 5px; if you want */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To fix it all.

Comment: Ah thanks so much! I've never used box-sizing so I would have never thought it would be relevant to me and I was just being stupid about the padding but I really appreciate it man!

Comment: Don't be sorry =) that's why we are all here. Great that it helped you!